# Vertical align issues Wordpress posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am having some problems with making sure my posts all line up vertically but they seem to be dropping when more are posted.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate the problem:

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; overflow: auto; height: auto;vertical-align: top;">
  <li style="float: left;background-color:blue;border:1px solid black; padding:10px; vertical-align: top;">
    <div style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ); width: 230px; height: 260px; background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
      <h2 style="margin:0; padding: 0;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                                <?php echo get_the_tag_list('<p> | ','&nbsp;&nbsp; | ','</p>'); ?>

</div>
</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: the vertical-align setting only takes effect if your elements are `display:inline-block` not when they're floated.

Comment: I have literally tried everything but struggling to find out what is going on here. I must be missing something.

Comment: It's something in your content. It would be nice if we could see the code at work instead of just an image but my best guess is there's some margin or padding issues in the content of each LI. The reason I say that is the li's themselves are side by side with your styling when I test it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `float: left` and replacing it with `display: inline-block`?

Comment: I have, is this because these are Wordpress post items within the loop so its stopping me from generating them like this?

Comment: No but I would say something about the default styling is messing with your layout. I can't say more without seeing the issue live so I can debug it. Do you have a live link I could see? The screenshot only gives me the visual aspect without seeing how the code is interacting.

Comment: I have just figured it out, I rewrote the loop and seems to be working, it was more than likely something I missed because it was just no behaving...I appreciate your response though :)

Comment: If you answer your own question you should try to describe your answer below so that other people looking for a similar issue will be able to fix theirs as well.